# running simple cmd.exe commands with apache commons exec

Tags: java, apache, cmd, apache-commons-exec

I want to run cmd.exe commands from java (for example md C:\blabla to create a new directory C:\blabla )
My code looks like this and it runs without any errors:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecuteException, IOException {
        CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("cmd.exe");
        cmdLine.addArgument("md");
        cmdLine.addArgument("C:\\blabla");
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.execute(cmdLine);
    }
}
```

But if I go to C:\ there is no folder blabla as I would expect, since manually typing md C:\blabla in cmd.exe works fine. I also tried "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" instead of "cmd.exe" but no use.

The output in the Console looks like this:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Selphiron\workspace\Test>

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is the command itself. Just try what you did in the command line.

Your code passes something like "cmd.exe md c:\blabla" to the system. That starts a new shell. Just passing a shell command to cmd.exe doesnt do the trick. Try to use

```
cmd /c md c:\blabla
```

The `/c` makes all the difference here.

Comment: Thx for your answer. It worked but what surprises me is that when I open cmd.exe and type md C:\blabla the new directory is created (Windows 7 64 bit).
Anyways thank you :)

Comment: Just giving a command to ``cmd.exe`` as parameter doesn't mean that cmd takes it and executes it. Check ``cmd.exe /?`` to check what the parameters do.